# How fast can a comparison based binary search tree construction algorithm take?

Tags: data-structures, tree, time-complexity, big-o

We know that an in order traversal of a binary search tree will list the elements of the tree in sorted order in O(n) time.
but how fast can a comparison based binary search tree construction algorithm take?

Comment: Do you know anything about the elements that need to be inserted into the binary tree or are they randomized?

Comment: Under-specified. If the input is already sorted it can be done in *O(N)* time. Knuth Vol 3, #6.2.3 Exercise 21.

Comment: Indeed @NickLarsen seems right! Time it takes will depend on the size and order of the elements that are input.

Answer (score -1):

The longest run time would be O (log n) in the worst case I think.

Comment: To construct a tree of N elements will take at least O(N) because you have to insert each element.